# Material ui drawer position

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui, drawer

How can I have drawer inside of dialog component in material-ui?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at rendered component, you will see the Drawer component has position "fixed. So to get the job done, just change it to "absolute".

Example code

```
<Drawer
  PaperProps={{
    style: {
      position: "absolute"
    }
  }}
  variant="permanent"
  anchor="left"
  open={openDrawer}
>
```

Just to focus on `PaperProps` and `variant` only. [Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-hill-lomgp?file=/src/App.js:2055-2279).

Comment: The problem is it is working only with variant="permanent", which I don't need. I am using swipableDrawer